# Does the block effort matter when mining in a pool? How does it impact earnings?

Tags: mining-pools

I've been using two or three pools so far. One of them always seems to need higher effort to find a block. Does that impact me personally in any way.
I've seen one go 600% and it took ages to get it. Did I lose time on it?
How does a 10% effort block change things then?

Answer (score 2):

The effort is just an educated guess based on the total pool hashrate.

At X Hashes/s, a block *should* be found in Y time.

I basically ignore it, its it a guess and not factual.